# Make a score counter work like a timer in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, handler, android-handler

I'm new to Java and working on my first app. I want the score to be displayed like a timer until it reaches the player's score. This is the code I've written.

```
Handler mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
int temp_score = 0;
while(temp_score<=score){
    final String score_string = "" + temp_score;
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            scoreTextView.setText(score_string);
        }
    }, 1000);
    temp_score++;
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working. When I run it, the app pauses for a while then shows the final score. It doesn't show it in intermediate steps. I have never used such a time based function. Can someone help me understand why this is happening? Also, can someone give me links where I could read up on postDelayed method more. I am not able to understand from developer.android site as I'm fairly new to it.

Thank you

Comment: `postDelayed` means that it will execute the `Runnable` once after a certain delay. You Runnable could run in an infinite loop to showcase your current score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Handler mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
int temp_score = 0;
int i = 0;
while(temp_score<=score){
    final String score_string = "" + temp_score++;
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            scoreTextView.setText(score_string);
        }
    }, ++i*1000);
}
```

Handlers are basicly objects asspciated with a single Thread and able to send messages, post instructions (Runnables) to it. postDelayed() is a delayed command post on the specified thread. Check the link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Your original solution is not working, because your while loop goes till it find the player's score and it creates a delayed run for every step but these are running so fast one after the other so you will notice only the last change.

Comment: The app stops responding.

Comment: It works perfectly!!! Thanks a lot!!! But can you explain your code a little? You added another integer which gets incremented every time in the loop. Shouldn't then the time interval keep on increasing in an AP? How does the ++i make the code run slower than before?

Comment: I changed the code to `++i*i*1` . It works much better now.

Comment: One last question. Why is the code which is after this being processed before the score counter reaches its final value?

Comment: Compare to the 1000ms time your while loop is running almost in the same time, so if you want to time  the events, you need to increase the delay time. You can assume that the different Runnable methods will be delayed from the 0 point to the given delay. I hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

```
  int temp_score = 0;
 Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                scoreTextView.setText(score_string);
            }
        });


       temp_score++;
    }
  }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
```